# Hide typed characters in tkinter.text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write little application similar to hyperTerminal:
Each character typed in Text widget is sent on serial port and each character received on the serial port is displayed in the Text widget.
The problem is the equipment connected to serial port returns an echo of characters it receives. So I get 2 characters in the Text widget (the typed and the echoed)

I tried to delete every typed characters, but I'm looking for a better solution.

```
def clavier(event):
    global sp
    edit.delete("insert-1c") # delete typed character
    try:
        sp.write(event.char.encode('Latin-1'))
    except:
        edit.insert(INSERT,'\nPort fermé, choisissez un port\n', 'rouge')

edit = Text(cadre, width=50,height=20,yscrollcommand = Vscroll.set)
edit.bind("<KeyRelease>", clavier)
```

Is there any way to hide the typed characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of how you are using the `Text` widget with the serial port, but it seems that you want to override the default action when you press the key. You can accomplish it by returning the string `"break"` in the handler function:

```
edit.bind("<KeyPress>", lambda e: "break")
```

I've tried it on Python 2.7 (with Tkinter 8.1) and I suppose it should also work on your versions, but if it does not, let me know.

Comment: Thank you A. Rodas,
Yes but how can I intercept the typed character to send it on serial port.

Normally in my program, the <KeyPress> event branch to my clavier function which receive the typed character in event.char and write it to the serial port

Comment: Do you mean how to do this with a handler already bound to the `"<KeyPress>"` event? In that case, just add `return "break"` at the end of the function.